# How to apply LUT in Da Vinci Resolve - no PhD in Color Science

Tags: davinci-resolve, color, lut

I downloaded a free LUT from the almighty Youtube and want to apply this Da Vinci Resolve. However there are plethora of options and 100 blogs telling 1000 different settings. Can someone give me a straight forward answer what settings to apply, please skip the PhD-level dcientific thesis about color science.

This is what I am seeing in my project settings under color management, which drop downs do I need to use to select my LUT?

[image]